# Reading a .txt file in python and separating it word by word

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

So basically I have a text file that I have to read word by word and return the longest word in the text without using libraries. I tried storing every word in a list and create a for loop to return the longest item in the list but my problem is that my output ends up being "tragical-pastoral-historical" which means my code doesn't obviously separate words separated by "-".

```
from os.path import join

path_prefix = "./drive/My Drive"
fileName = 'hamlet.txt'

def longest_word(fileName):
  with open(join(path_prefix, fileName), newline='') as myFile:
    wordsList = list(myFile.read().split())
    longestWord = ''
    for i in range(len(wordsList)):
      if (len(wordsList[i]) > len(longestWord)):
        longestWord = wordsList[i]
  print(longestWord)

longest_word('hamlet.txt')
```

Comment: Can you add it - to space brake in array ?

Comment: @pc_ I am fairly new to python so can you elaborate?

Comment: You splitting words with a space brake, see: newline=' '  ,      add '-' or any other delimiter you want into array.

Comment: I read in some websites that it was about the split() function since its default seperator is a white space but if I add anything else there like '-' then it stops counting space as a seperator. I don't know how can I alter the newline=' ' part as you said

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'-'` with `' '` before splitting is done.
If only dashes are the problem, the following should work.

```
from os.path import join

path_prefix = "./drive/My Drive"
fileName = 'hamlet.txt'

def longest_word(fileName):
  with open(join(path_prefix, fileName), newline='') as myFile:
    wordsList = list(myFile.read().replace('-', ' ').split())  # replace '-' by ' ' prior to splitting
    longestWord = ''
    for word in wordsList:  # simplified loop
      if len(word) > len(longestWord):
        longestWord = word
  print(longestWord)

longest_word('hamlet.txt')
```

Comment: Note this will give you the last longest word

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we happen to have a text file `try.txt`:

```
this is line of a text
this is another line of a text
```

Then in pure Python you can proceed as follows:

```
with open("try.txt") as f:
    txt = f.read().split()
l = list(map(len,txt))
m = max(l)
pos = [i for i,j in enumerate(l) if j==m]
[txt[p] for p in pos]
['another']
```

Another one of interest that will give you the first longest word:

```
with open("try.txt") as f:
    txt = f.read().split()
max(txt, key = len)
'another'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to import the split method from the library 're' (stands for regular expressions).

So for example in your case :

```
from re import split as resplit

from os.path import join

path_prefix = "./drive/My Drive"
fileName = 'hamlet.txt'

def longest_word(fileName):
  with open(join(path_prefix, fileName), newline='') as myFile:
    wordsList = list(resplit('[ -]',myFile.read()))
    longestWord = ''
    for i in range(len(wordsList)):
      if (len(wordsList[i]) > len(longestWord)):
        longestWord = wordsList[i]
  print(longestWord)

longest_word('hamlet.txt')
```

In the first argument of resplit in between the [] you specify all the characters to split.